# python subprocess become idle after a while

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

I have two script, one is for reading serial port continuously and other script is for running the serial port reading script in background. The script given below is I used for running as subprocess.

```
subprocess.Popen("echo " + user_password + " | sudo -S " + filePath  shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

if i run serial port reading script manually, it will not idle, it runs contineously. But if i use the above script for running as subprocess, the serial port reading script become idle after a few minutes. How i can stop this idle issue?

Comment: curious but does it stop if you idle your pyhton script afterwards? something like while(true); time.sleep(1)

Comment: Script isn't stopping, it shows as running in background, but the script isn't responding

Comment: Instead of relying on shell, you could directly invoke `sudo` like `Popen(["sudo", "-S", filePath], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` and feed the password in. It may simplify the issue. Also, what are you using for IPC, `communcate()` or `proc.stdout`?

Comment: sorry, how to set password in this case, @minmaxavg

Comment: That depends on your answer to my last question.

Comment: hi @minmaxavg, i'm just a beginner with python, and i'm running the sub process command using, gui build using tkinter, Because of i'm a beginner, i don't understand, your last question :(

Comment: Do you use the result of `Popen` to another variable, or is the code you posted the entire line? If latter, you should take out the `, stdout=subprocess.PIPE` because that means the Python code is and should be reading and processing the command's standard output. If not, then chances are it's an OS-related issue.

Comment: I don't using the result of Popen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, if you go for multi processing instead of subprocess, you don't get idle issue

http://answerexpress.blogspot.com/2018/09/python-subprocess-become-idle-after_15.html

Answer (score 0):

You defined `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` which allows you to read the output of command by saving them to a buffer memory. But if you don't use/read it, that memory become full after a certain time and subprocess will hang util you use it. You can avoid that issue by passing `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL`, or not specifying anything with `stdout`.